# Mockito showing 0 interactions with mock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

Here is my code:

```
public class S3Dao {

    private final AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client;

    static final String BUCKET_NAME = "myBucket";

    public S3Dao(final AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client) {
        this.amazonS3Client = amazonS3Client;
    }

    public void put(ModelObject modelObject, String playlistId) {
        this.amazonS3Client.putObject(BUCKET_NAME, playlistId, new Gson().toJson(modelObject));
    }
}
```

And my test code:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class S3DaoTest {

    private S3Dao s3Dao;

    @Mock
    private AmazonS3Client s3Client;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach() {
        this.s3Dao = new S3Dao(this.s3Client);
    }

    @Test
    public void putTest() {
        ModelObject obj = new ModelObject("name", new ArrayList<>());
        String json = new Gson().toJson(obj);
        verify(s3Client).putObject(S3Dao.BUCKET_NAME, "playlistId", json);

        this.s3Dao.put(obj, "playlistId");
    }

}
```

The resulting error is

```
Wanted but not invoked:
s3Client.putObject(
    "myBucket",
    "playlistId",
    "{"name":"name","children":[]}"
);
-> at com.amazon.amazon.live.destination.playlist.dao.S3DaoTest.putTest(S3DaoTest.java:34)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Indeed, removing the verify causes the test to pass without issue. Why isn't this working?

Comment: Verify verifies at method `verify` invocation. Ints not a rule, its runtime in place check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the verify after the method call

```
@Test
public void putTest() {
    ModelObject obj = new ModelObject("name", new ArrayList<>());
    String json = new Gson().toJson(obj);
    this.s3Dao.put(obj, "playlistId");

    verify(s3Client).putObject(S3Dao.BUCKET_NAME, "playlistId", json);
}
```